# How to find the number of possible combinatons of 1s and 0s to complete one row in the game of picross ignoring column restrictions

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, puzzle

I'm programming an AI for solving picross puzzles, to optimize it, it would be very helpful to know which row has the least possible valid combinations.

What I've figured out is that given the constraints of a row i can calculate the number of valid combinations with generating functions in the following manner.

A valid row might be visualized as:

`|2 3|□ □ ■ ■ □ □ □ ■ ■ ■ □|`

m is the size of the row in question.
Given the constraints of a row as: $c = (c_1, c_2, ..., c_n)$
s = $\sum^{n}_{i=1}c_i$
$x_i$ is the size of the gap between $c_{i-1}$ and $c_i$
We find the number of combinations of $x_i$ that satisfy the following equation:
$m = \sum^{n}_{i=1}c_i + \sum^{n+1}_{i=1}x_i$
$m - \sum^{n}_{i=1}c_i = \sum^{n+1}_{i=1}x_i$
$m-s = x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_{n+1}$

Notice that the gaps can't be 0 with the exception of the first and last ones.
From this we define the polynomial $P(x)$:
$P(x)=(x+x^2+x^3+...)^{n-1} \cdot (1+x+x^2+...)^2$
The solution to our problem will then be the coefficient of order $m-s$ of $P(x)$, that would be enough for me, since i can easily calculate that coefficient in my code.

Now the problem is that i might have an incomplete row where i know that some of the cells should be colored in, and others that shouldn't, but there are some cells for which i have not enough information.

An example of an incomplete row might be visualized as:

`|2 3|□ ? ■ ? □ ? ? ■ ? ? □|`

How could I solve this problem?

By the way, the AI which I'm talking about is open source and can be found [here](https://github.com/eugenioLR/Picross_AI).

It might be hard to understand since there's almost no comments yet, also, it has no GUI for the moment, but I'm still working on it.

Comment: In your incomplete row example, you can assign the variables $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$, $x_4$ for the (possible) gaps falling within the four question mark areas "?","?","??","??", then you will have $x_1+x_2=2-1=1$, $x_3+x_4=3-1=2$, $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4 \ge 0$. You compute the solutions of both equations (with the generating functions, like you have already done, or better with the binomial coefficients of the [star and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) method and then multiply them together.

Comment: In case of a row like this ``|2 3|□ ? ■ ? ? ? ? ? ? ? □|`` you will have $x_1+x_2+x_3=8-1-3=4$, with $x_1, x_3 \ge 0$ and $x_2 \ge 1$, which letting $y_2=x_2-1$ can be modified in $x_1+y_2+x_3=3$ and $x_1, y_2, x_3 \ge 0$.

Comment: At worst, you can look at each of the $2^n$ possibilities, where $n$ is the number of no-information cells, and count how many match the description.  This is already tractable.  Doing DFS and filling cells in from left to right (say) will be much more efficient, since you can backtrack early once the first few cells are seen to be wrong.

Comment: @mjqxxxx that's roughly what i was already doing, but i wanted a more elegant solution, in all honesty that solution works well.

Comment: I suspect there won’t be a more elegant solution... but that’s a guess.  My intuition is that a well-commented, straightforward tree search in this case will be equally efficient, and much more readable to an average coder, compared to any generating function approach.

Comment: @mjqxxxx probably, but this project is more like an excuse for me to learn about AI and math, so I'm ok if the code is not that intuitive, anyhow, thanks for the advise.

Comment: @BillyJoe Thank you, that makes sense, although I'm having a bit of trouble putting it into code, but i'll figure it out.

Comment: In case you don't have hints, the number of possible solutions is $m-s+1 \choose n$. You can see this by removing all the black cells that are not the first of their block, and the white cells following each block (except for the last block). This gives $m-s+1$ cells remaining. You need to place the $n$ starts of the blocks in these $m-s+1$ cells.